# How to get Facebook recommendations in PHP (custom format like on CNN.com)

Tags: facebook

Any idea how to get recommended links on for my site on Facebook with PHP? Is there FB query for that?
Example is CNN site (www.cnn.com). They have "Popular on Facebook" list on right side.

Comment: Which page on CNN for the `Popular on Facebook`?

Answer (score 0):

You can you insights.

1. Setup [insights for your website](http://www.facebook.com/insights/)
2. Use FQL insights to retrieve the data [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/)